# SciPy SVD vs. Numpy SVD

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, svd

Both SciPy and Numpy have built in functions for singular value decomposition (SVD). The commands are basically `scipy.linalg.svd` and `numpy.linalg.svd`. What is the difference between these two? Is any of them better than the other one?

Comment: I don't know about the main behavior, but the `scipy` version has two additional options: 1) `overwrite_a`, which allows in-place modifications to the input and would reduce memory usage and possibly speed it up, and 2) `check_finite` which allows you to have the call assume the array is finite, saving some small overhead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [FAQ page](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#why-both-numpy-linalg-and-scipy-linalg-what-s-the-difference), it says `scipy.linalg` submodule provides a more complete wrapper for the Fortran LAPACK library whereas `numpy.linalg` tries to be able to build independent of LAPACK.

I did some [benchmarks](https://towardsdatascience.com/turbocharging-svd-with-jax-749ae12f93af) for the different implementation of the `svd` functions and found `scipy.linalg.svd` is faster than the numpy counterpart:

[image]

However, [jax](https://github.com/google/jax) wrapped numpy, aka `jax.numpy.linalg.svd` is even faster:

[image]

Full notebook for the benchmarks are available [here](https://gist.github.com/wangz10/d6f43db76ca260516d149d92b8834bf9).

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of jax.

Comment: These are somewhat moving targets.  On both Windows and Linux, using either OpenBLAS or MKL, the performance of NumPy and SVD are now identical. JAX may still be faster, I did not test it.

Comment: Would you know of any real, not random, benchmarks ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the error checking, the actual work seems to be done within [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node32.html)
both with `numpy` and `scipy`.

Without having done any benchmarking, I guess the performance should be identical.

Answer (score 2):

Another distinction is that `np.linalg.svd` can do vectorized `svd` calculations over large data arrays, where `sp.linalg.svd` will only do 1 at a time.

ex:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

data = np.random.random((3,3))             # a single matrix
data_array = np.random.random((10**6,3,3)) # one million matrices

# numpy svd
R,S,V = np.linalg.svd(data)       # works
R,S,V = np.linalg.svd(data_array) # works

# scipy svd
R,S,V = sp.linalg.svd(data)       # works
R,S,V = sp.linalg.svd(data_array) # fails !!!
```

I have not benchmarked this, but while a direct 1:1 comparison between the two might show `sp.linalg.svd` to be faster to compute, `np.linalg.svd` might be faster (or at least more convenient) when you need to compute the `svd` over a large data array.