# How to get all three SVD matrices with sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pca, svd

[Singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of matrix `M` of size `(M,N)` means factoring

[image]

How to obtain all three matrices from `scikit-learn` and `numpy` package?

I think I can obtain `Sigma` with [`PCA` model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

model = PCA(N, copy=True, random_state=0)
model.fit(X)

Sigma = model.singular_values_
Sigma = np.diag(singular_values)
```

What about other matrices?

Answer (score 2):

You can get these matrices using [`numpy.linalg.svd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html#numpy.linalg.svd) as follows:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=True)
```

`S` is a `1D` array that represents the diagonal entries in `Sigma`. `U` and `V` are the corresponding matrices from the decomposition.

By the way, note that when you used `PCA`, the data is centered before svd is applied (unlike `numpy.linalg.svd`, where svd is applied directly on the matrix itself. see lines 409-410 [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L395)).

Comment: Is this equivalent to PCA when data is noisy? Can't `np.linalg.svd` just throw an exception while `PCA` estimator will still run?

Comment: I don't see why it should be equivalent. PCA code in GitHub also uses numpy.linalg.svd (this is shown in the link I provided in the answer). The only difference is that in the PCA code they use full_matrices=False and they center the data prior to the decomposition, but it is still the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on Mirian's answer because I don't have enough reputation, but from looking at Miriam's link, sklearn actually calls scipy's `linalg.svd` which is doesn't seem to be the same as np.linalg.svd [(discussion here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569188/scipy-svd-vs-numpy-svd)

So it may be better to use `U, S, V = scipy.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=True)`