# Convert cuml (RAPIDS) truncatedSVD into sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd, rapids

I have to convert a code written using cuml (RAPIDS) into sklearn.

I found out that in `cuml.truncatedSVD` the parameter `n_components` which is the output dimensions (number of singular values) can equal to the number of inputs/features in cuml, but not in `sklearn.decomposition.truncatedSVD` which requires a value strictly inferior to the input dimensions.

The cuml code I'm converting takes two features as inputs and computes two singular values, which is impossible with sklearn.

Is there a way workaround or a way to make it work with sklearn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `SVD` methods in `scipy` (faster in my case) or `numpy`. You can find more information in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569188/scipy-svd-vs-numpy-svd).